# Fetching DLLs from NuGet if Deleted

Tags: nuget

I've done a fair bit of reading on NuGet, and I can't seem to find what I want. Essentially, I'm hoping that it will work like Apache Ivy, where you can just check in your config file (without any binaries) and tell NuGet to fetch all the DLLs -- thus saving you from versioning tons of DLLs.

Hence: **is there a command in NuGet to fetch and configure all dependencies mentioned in `packages.config`?**

Again, the case for this is that I only checked packages.config into source control, not the actual DLLs, and I need to re-fetch everything. (Preferably without fetching packages one by one by name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been covered recently in blog posts:

- Inbuilt functionality for this is coming in a future version of NuGet: http://feeds.haacked.com/~r/haacked/~3/x8g_kFzD4eA/feedback-request-for-using-nuget-without-committing-packages.aspx
- (Linked from above) How to do this today using command line `NuGet.exe` (available from the [NuGet pages](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/55760) on CodePlex): http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html

EDIT: Now also covered on [NuGet's Documentation Pages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)