# How to fix deleted DLLs from NuGet's packages?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

With `NuGet`, I added `Json.NET` (`Newtonsoft.Json`) to my code. As result of a mistake (adding code to CMS, ignoring DLLs, and checking out), my reference DLLs were deleted.

How do I restore ?

I followed all links in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847885/fetching-dlls-from-nuget-if-deleted), but nothing brings back the DLLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still have the packages.config file you should be able to use [nuget.exe to restore the packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Install_Command) in the packages folder. You can run nuget install followed by the path to your packages.config file.

```
nuget install packages.config
```

This will restore the packages to the packages folder but not modify your project.

If you do not have the packages.config file you could try running nuget install specifying the package id and the version instead.

If you have files in your packages folder you may want to remove those before running this command.

Comment: `nuget install c:\path\packages.config` gives me `The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ...`. Am I supposed to type it in the `Package Manager Console` ?

Comment: Either add the directory to nuget.exe to your PATH environment variable or copy nuget.exe to the folder you are running the command from.